# Why does it display an ERROR 1146 "Table 'student.db' doesn't exist', though I already create 'student' database?

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

After I created database 'student', when I set authorities about the db, error occurred with the message "ERROR 1146(42S02) : Table 'student.db' doesn't exist.
I can't understand why this kind error happened, though I surely created the database.

Could you let me know what the problem is?

Please, refer below step to reproduce.

```
Start mysql with root account
create database student;
use student;

insert into db values ('%', 'student', 'beginner', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y');
```

Error occurred...... "ERROR 1146(42S02) : Table 'student.db' doesn't exist.

I can check that student database exists by using 'show databases;'. but this message says "student.db" doesn't exist.

Comment: you don't have the table `db` in `student` database.

Comment: yep.. now I got what the problem is.. thx

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are trying to grant privileges by modifying the system tables directly.  There is a table `mysql.db` in every MySQL instance, but that table does not belong to your `student` database.

I recommend you use the GRANT statement instead of tinkering with system data directly:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'beginner'@'%' identified by 'enter password here';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON student.* to 'beginner';
```

Comment: Must say, you are probably the only one that saw this.

Comment: Thanks, the statement cannot be applied to the student database as you said. Because, it doesn't have db table.
Now, I've got to know what I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

student.db refers to a TABLE named **db** inside the `student` database. You obviously did not create this table yet...
b.t.w. read carefully the error message and what you thought the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
insert into db values ('%', 'student', 'beginner', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y');
```

assumes that at some point, the table named `db` has been created:

```
create table db ( ...
```

Based on what you've shown here, you don't seem to have created it; where did you expect its definition to come from?

Answer (score 0):

You've created a database, but haven't created any tables in it. You're telling MySQL to insert your data into a table name "db", which doesn't exist. You need to have something like this goin gon:

```
create database student;
use student;
create table db (.... field definitions here ...)  <---you're missing this step
insert into db values (....);
```

A database is just a container. It must have at least ONE table defined in it to actually be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was...
You have a DB with "InnoDB ENGINE"....... 
My Solution was...
You must have a "MyISAM ENGINE", 
how to change?...  find on your environment may be with

```
# find / -name my.cnf
```

on LINUX, simply add the following line to

```
$ vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf 

default-storage-engine= MyISAM
```

Then restart mysql:

```
$ service mysql restart
```